# There is no default content in joomla 3.1

Tags: joomla

I am new to joomla, so i recently downloaded joomla 3.1 after installing it in my localhost i am not able to proceed further in creating a website since there is no default content in joomla 3.1 when compared to joomla 2.5.

Is there any way to enable the content from administrator login ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, default content is installed  as part of the setup process.

If all you've done is install Joomla, then I suggest you delete the installation and re-install Joomla, this time selecting the option to install one of the "Sample Data" groups:

1. List itemBlog English (GB) Sample Data
2. Brochure English (GB) Sample Data
3. Default English (GB) Sample Data
4. Learn Joomla English (GB) Sample Data
5. Test English (GB) Sample Data

You'll find this option on the third and final tab before the installation proceeds, as shown below:
[image: Joomla 3.1 Final Installation Step]